# Haskell: Are all instances necessary for type checking?

Tags: haskell, types

I am studying how type class instances can be used to check the type correctness of methods in complex class hierarchies. This question is related to, but distinct from, a [previous post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/haskell-type-classes-as-ontological-categories).

The `BoatHouses` and `HouseBoats` classes are at the bottom of the class hierarchy and thus require instances of the super classes to exist before they themselves can be instantiated. When I attempted  to construct instances for these classes I found that I had to add 72 instances to satisfy the compiler. I arrived at the number 72 by first attempting to make instances for `BoatHouses` and `HouseBoats` and then following the compiler messages as to what other classes needed to be instantiated.  Form the **Listing 1** (most method signatures omitted) and **Listing 2** below there are 13 data types, there are 14 classes, 45 type variables. This code is based on a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1EA31D76684217BC728F916144BC6C38?doi=10.1.1.109.6853&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but actual details and purpose of the code are not important for my question.

**Question**

To type check methods specified at the lower end of a complex class lattice is it really necessary to instantiate **all** the classes suggested by compiler?

**Listing 1**

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#  OPTIONS_GHC  -Wno-missing-methods #-} 
class Containers a b where
     insert :: b -> a b -> a b
     remove :: b -> a b -> a b
     whatsIn :: a b -> [b]


    class Surfaces a b where
     put ::  b -> a b -> a b
     takeOff :: b -> a b -> a b
     whatsOn :: a b -> [b]

    class Contacts a b where
     attach :: b -> a b -> a b
     detach :: b -> a b -> a b
     whatsAt :: a b -> [b]

    class Paths a b c where
     move :: c -> a b c -> a b c
     origin, destination :: a b c -> b
     whereIs :: a b c -> c -> b

    class People p
    class HeavyLoads l
    class Surfaces w o => WaterBodies w o
    class Containers h o => Houses h o
    class (Surfaces v o, Paths a b (v o)) => Vehicles v o a b
    class (Vehicles v o a b, WaterBodies w (v o)) => Vessels v o a b w
    class (Vessels v p a b w, People p) => Boats v p a b w
    class (Boats v p a b w, HeavyLoads p) => Barges v p a b w
    class (Houses h (v p), Boats v p a b w, Contacts w (h (v p))) => BoatHouses h v p a b w
    class (Barges v p a b w, Houses v p, People p) => HouseBoats v p a b w
```

**Listing 2**

```
data Person = Person deriving Show
data Vehicle a =  Vehicle a deriving Show
data Vessel a = Vessel a deriving Show
data House a = House a  deriving Show
data HouseBoat a = HouseBoat a  deriving Show
data Boat a  = Boat a deriving Show
data BoatHouse a  = BoatHouse a deriving Show
data Barge a = Barge  a deriving Show
data Path a b = Path a b deriving Show
data Source = Source deriving Show
data Destination = Destination deriving Show
data Water a = Water a deriving Show
data Land a = Land a deriving Show
```

Comment: Is listing 2 a mock-up or is that the real code? Concretely, do you plan to change those type definitions in listing 2? It is weird to see that many wrappers: your types are all variants of `()`, `Identity a`, and `(a,b)`. For such repetitive tasks, one could use Template Haskell or some newtype auto-derivation. If they are only stubs, and you really need different instances, then you will need to write all of them by hand.

Comment: @ch1 Listing 2 consists of types identified in the original paper e.g. the type variable 'h' is instantiated with the type 'House'. The type, classes and instances all compile.

Comment: @chi There are as you say better ways of doing this, but I am interested in working with code as near as possible to the original paper.